# numpy array shape changed after inserted mean

Tags: python, arrays

I have an numpy array which I want to insert 3 means into it. The array shape was (1, 23) before i inserted mean. However, it changed to (26,) after I inserted means. Is there anyway to make the shape like (1, 26) ?

the array

```
array([[ 266,  356,  252,  282,    3,  644, 1254,  634,    4,  711,   58,
        1006,  782,  613,  565,    2,  787,  968,  640,    4,  676,  530,
         573]])
```

the code

```
mean = myarray.mean()
myarray= np.append(myarray, np.array([mean,mean,mean]))
```

Comment: Use `myarray = myarray.reshape(1,-1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the axis along which you append so something like this:

```
myarray= np.append(myarray, [[mean,mean,mean]], axis=1)
```

Should work. (note the extra set of brackets so that both arrays have same number of dimensions).

Answer (score 1):

m= mean.astype(int)

myarray=np.append(myarray,[[m,m,m]], axis=1)

Now following command will give output as (1, 26)

myarray.shape